# Effectively find first common element in two sequences

Tags: c#, linq

I got two sequences as `IEnumerable<MyClass>` with the special property that there is a guarantee that from a certain position on (which might be different in the two sequences), all of their elements are equal. There are no repetitions in each of the sequences. Example:

> Sequence a: F, G, Z, **M, N, O, ...**
> Sequence b: L, A, **M, N, O, ...**

I need to find the first equal element (in the above example: M).

For sure, I can do the following:

```
public MyClass FindFirstCommonElement(IEnumerable<MyClass> a, IEnumerable<MyClass> b)
{
   var h = new HashSet<MyClass>(a);
   return b.First(x => h.Contains(x));
}
```

The drawback is that this needs to materialize (completely enumerate) one of the sequences.
If the sequences are potentially huge and/or expensive to calculate, this is not optimal. In my case, the sequences are generated by a method containing `yield return` in a loop. Luckily, they are guaranteed to be finite but the size cannot be determined (easily) beforhand and might be > 1 million.

I'm aware that in the worst case there is no way around enumerating both sequences to the end but if the typical case has the first common element early, there should be a more efficient way.

**Edit**
As pointed out in the comments, possible improvements highly depend on the shape of the input data. I my case, the in most cases the first match was within the first 1000 elements, so I came up with the following implementation of SomeBody's idea:

```
public T FindFirstCommonElement<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b, int guessedMaximumIndex)
{
  var valuesFromA = new HashSet<T>();
  var valuesFromB = new List<T>();

  using (var enumeratorA = a.GetEnumerator())
  using (var enumeratorB = b.GetEnumerator())
  {
    // first iterate at max the first guessedMaximumIndex elements to find an early match
    for (var i = 0; i < guessedMaximumIndex; i++)
    {
      if (!enumeratorA.MoveNext())
        break;
      valuesFromA.Add(enumeratorA.Current);
      if (!enumeratorB.MoveNext())
        break;
      valuesFromB.Add(enumeratorB.Current);
    }
    var match = valuesFromB.FirstOrDefault(x => valuesFromA.Contains(x));
    if (!Equals(match, default(T)))
      return default(T); // early match found
    
    // iterate the rest of a  
    while (enumeratorA.MoveNext())
      valuesFromA.Add(enumeratorA.Current);
    // do we now find a match with the already enumerated values of b?
    match = valuesFromB.FirstOrDefault(x => valuesFromA.Contains(x));
    if (!Equals(match, default(T)))
      return default(T);
    // enumerate the rest of b unti we find a match
    while (enumeratorB.MoveNext())
    {
      if (valuesFromB.Contains(enumeratorB.Current))
        return enumeratorB.Current;
    }
    return default(T);
  }
}
```

Indeed, with some of my real-word data, most of the time the early match did it and in these cases the search speed-up was very considerable. Also if the ealy exit was not taken, the time was not comparablen with my original approach.

**Edit 2**: the accepted answer is even faster and much easier

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem ?

Comment: Maybe you can check for the first 100 elements of both your sequences. If the common element is not found, you'll take the next 100 elements and so on. But this has the drawback that you will have to enumerate the first 100 elements of your b sequence multiple times.

Comment: Is it possible for Sequence a: to be  F, G, Z, M, N, O and Sequence b: G, L, A, M, N, O to be? If so, what result are you looking for (G or M)?

Comment: Another option to consider would be `var result = a.Reverse().Zip(b.Reverse(), (a1, b1) => new { a1, b1 }).TakeWhile(z => z.a1 == z.b1).LastOrDefault()?.a1;` (but it may perform poorly for large sets of data).

Comment: @PeterDuniho There are no repetitions in each of the sequences. I added this to the question.

Comment: @mjwills: No, this is not possible. Once there is a match, the rest of the two sequences is identical

Comment: Is the size of the sequences known?

Comment: @mjwills @grek40 The equences are generated by a method containing `yield return` in a loop. Luckily, they are finite but the size cannot be determined (easily) and might be > million.

Comment: A million entries should fit fine in a `HashSet` (especially if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element is on). Did you profile `a.Intersect(b).FirstOrDefault()` in that scenario? How long did it take? https://dotnetfiddle.net/hHBOzq

Comment: Its worth noting that `IEnumerable<T>` says nothing about order. For example, `HashSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @mjwills The Intersect method (which is equivalentto the HashSet method in my question) took a few seconds in a typical case. About 50 times slower than the code in your dotnetfiddle because both the generator takes longer than `Enumerator<int>.Range` and also the `Equals` implementation is slower than `int.Equals`

Comment: Sure - but any solution is likely going to be impacted by the slow generator and the slow `Equals`. Is a few seconds acceptable?

Comment: @SomeBody interesting idea. This would be indeed faster if most of the matches are in postions < 100. I will try and measure. If I remember the already enumerated elements in a List, there would also be no need to enumerate again.

Comment: The challenge here is understanding the common cases. @SomeBody's idea will speed it up for some cases, slow it down for others. Different implementations will scale differently. Whatever solution you decide on will need to be profiled with different scenarios (e.g. large sets of data where only the last element is equal, large sets of data where all elements are equal etc etc).

Comment: @mjwills The slow generator only has such a big effect if I'm forced to materialize the sequence. Otherwise it is only called a few times. Of course this depends on the distribution of the matching point in the real world cases.

Comment: Yes - the shape of the data very much impacts the best algorithm to choose.

Comment: Take a step back - can you explain what these sequences are? Why does it matter to find the first match? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, if we can assume a distribution, where in the common case the matching sequence starts before half of the elements are enumerated, it can be beneficial to enumerate both sequences step by step instead of enumerating one sequence first and then the other.

```
private T Resolve<T>(IEnumerable<T> in1, IEnumerable<T> in2)
{
    var visited = new HashSet<T>();

    using (var enumerator1 = in1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumerator2 = in2.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            bool hasNext1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
            bool hasNext2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

            if (hasNext1 && !visited.Add(enumerator1.Current))
                return enumerator1.Current;

            if (hasNext2 && !visited.Add(enumerator2.Current))
                return enumerator2.Current;

            if (!hasNext1 && !hasNext2)
                break;
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

I decided to post my approach since it works in cases where the result sequence of one input starts at a position greater than the length of the other sequence.

Comment: If this is used to compare two very large sets of data with no overlapping values, then it will generate a `HashSet` twice as large as the vanilla `Intersect` solution. _I am not saying that is good or bad - but it means both sets are enumerated **and** maximum memory is used. Of course, there is no right answer here (it is all tradeoffs) but it does mean this solution scales particularly poorly for that scenario._

Comment: @mjwills you are definitely right... if the result is found within the first half of the *smaller collection*, it will save some memory, but as soon as the result is within the second half of the *first collection*, it consumes more memory than `Intersect` and generally, as soon as it is within the second half of the *smaller collection*, a better approach could be found. Intersect would probably scale poorly in a scenario where the first collection is considerable larger than the second collection... there is no silver bullet for random distributed input data, only for specific cases.

Comment: `there is no silver bullet for random distributed input data, only for specific cases.` Well summarised.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding iterated entries to a set and than checking that.

```
var a = new List<char>() {'F', 'G', 'Z', 'M', 'N', 'O'};
var b = new List<char>() {'L', 'A', 'M', 'N', 'O'};

var found = new HashSet<char>();
char same = default(char);
using (var ae = a.GetEnumerator())
using (var be = b.GetEnumerator())
{
    var an = true;
    var bn = true;
    while (an || bn)
    {
        an = ae.MoveNext();
        bn = be.MoveNext();
        if (bn && !found.Add(be.Current))
        {
            same = be.Current;
            break;
        }
        if (an && !found.Add(ae.Current))
        {
            same = ae.Current;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(same);
```

Comment: Was just working on a similar approach... however, I think one HashSet for both collections would be enough, since the first intersecting item is the requested result.

Comment: @grek40 Im thinking with a single set we might get problems if the same entity occurs twice in the same collection. (that was my initial thought at least)

Comment: Works very good. Shouldn't `ae` and `be` be `Dispose`d?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes they should

Comment: @Magnus I was taking this info from comments: *"@PeterDuniho There are no repetitions in each of the sequences. I added this to the question."* So, in the special requested case it should be ok

Comment: "if the same entity occurs twice in the same collection": this cannot happen (a least in my case)

Comment: Ok, than my first answer with single set should work :-) I'll roll back the update.

Comment: @mjwills In terms of memory I guess it is impossible to know upfront which solution would be the best. It all depends on the sequence. But for performance I think this would work the best.